# Create signature verify message with IOS below 14

Tags: ios, swift, signature

I"m using P256 to create signature verify message ( Code below ) . However It's only support IOS above 14.
I try create signature by SecKeyCreateSignature but don't verify. Backend I'm using Java and X509 Algothrim .

```
    let keyData = privateKeyHexaString.hexadecimal!
    let privateKey = try! P256.Signing.PrivateKey(derRepresentation: keyData)
    let signData = getStringHash("Hello").data(using: .utf8)
    let sig = try! privateKey.signature(for: "Hello".data(using: .utf8)!)        
    
    let verify = try! privateKey.publicKey.isValidSignature(sig, for: "Hello".data(using: .utf8)!)
    print("signDer \(sig.derRepresentation.base64EncodedString())")
```

Comment: I"m using ecdsaSignatureMessageX962SHA512 algothrim